# Why are my variables resetting to zero - perl

Tags: regex, perl

Would anyone be able to tell me why everything else works except for my USER and PASS counter variables towards the bottom of my 'while' loop? something resets them to zero when they should output 3 for user and 2 for pass.

(The code is counting how many instances there are of the word USER and PASS by the way.)

And if you see any other sloppy errors, please let me know! Thanks ahead!!

First line of the input file (note: this format repeats for 2006 lines, only the numbers change)

```
22:28:31.819551 IP 98.114.205.102.1924 > 192.150.11.111.1957: Flags [P.], seq 1:124, ack 2, win 64239, length 123E...<.@.q...br.f...o....\.bfP....Y..echo USER 1 get ssms.exe
```

**Code:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

open MYFILE, '<', 'source_file.txt' or die $!;
open OUT, '>', 'Summary_Report.txt' or die $!;
open OUTFILE, '>', 'Header.txt' or die $!;

my $start_time = undef;
my $end_time;
my $user = 0;
my $pass = 0;
my $linenum = 0;

while (<MYFILE>) {              # loops through every line in file
    chomp;                      # break new line
    $linenum++;                 # count line 1 to end of file, 2006
    if (/^\d+:\d+/) {
        my @header = split (/\s+/, $_);
        print OUTFILE "$linenum: @header\n\n";
        if (/^22:28/ && !defined($start_time)) {
            $start_time = $header[0];
        }
        if (/22:28/) {
            $end_time = $header[0];
        }
        $user++ if /USER/ig;
        $pass++ if /PASS/ig;
    }
}

print OUT "Total # of times phrases were used:\n\n
   USER (variations thereof) = $user\n\n
   PASS (variations thereof) = $pass\n\n\n";
```

---

okay everyone, here's EVERY last bit of my code.
(the outputs are not finished yet, thats why some are still unanswered, but you can get an idea of what I am working on and what needs to be done.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

# Final project
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

#opens txt file: read mode
open MYFILE, '<', 'source_file.txt' or die $!;

#opens output txt file: write mode
open OUT, '>', 'Summary_Report.txt' or die $!;

#open output txt file: write mode
#used to store header 'split' info
open OUTFILE, '>', 'Header.txt' or die $!;

my $i = 0;
$| = 1; #disable output buffering

my $start_time = undef; #undefined to avoid recycling through other time stamps
my $end_time;

my $user = 0;
my $pass = 0;

my $packet_size = 0; #goes with length#

my @header;

my @source_ip;
my @source_port;
my $src_port;
my @src_port;

my @dest_ip;
my @dest_port;
my $destination_port;
my @destination_port;


while (<MYFILE>) { #loops through every line in file
    chomp; #break new line

    if (/^\d+:\d+/) {

    #separate pieces of information from TCPDUMP into list
    @header = split (/\s+/, $_);
    print OUTFILE "$.: @header\n\n";

##############################T I M E##################################

    #defining first 'line & time' as 'special'
    if (/^22:28/ && !defined($start_time)) {
        $start_time = $header[0];
        #print "$start_time\n"; ###used as a check###
    }   

    #Used recycling of time stamps to find last one available
    if (/22:28/) {
        $end_time = $header[0];
    }       

#############################S O U R C E#################################

    #categorizing each section of ip's from source
    @source_ip = split ('\.', $header[2]);

    #adding ip's together, joining in concatenation by '.'
    $source_ip[$i] = $source_ip[0] . '.' . $source_ip[1] . '.' . $source_ip[2] . '.' .      $source_ip[3];
    #print $source_ip[$i]; (check)

    @source_port = split (':', $source_ip[4]);
    $src_port[$i] = $source_port[0];

#########################D E S T I N A T I O N###########################

    #categorizing each section of ip's from destination
    @dest_ip = split ('\.', $header[4]);

    #adding ip's together, joining in concatenation by '.'
    $dest_ip[$i] = $dest_ip[0] . '.' . $dest_ip[1] . '.' . $dest_ip[2] . '.' . $dest_ip[3];
    #print $dest_ip[$i]; (check)

    @dest_port = split (':', $source_ip[4]);
    $destination_port[$i] = $dest_port[0];

#############################L E N G T H#################################

    #-1 represents length
    $packet_size = $packet_size + $header[-1];
    #print $packet_size; (check)

    $i++
    }
}

close MYFILE;

#########################D A T A S E C T I O N###########################

open MYFILE, '<', 'source_file.txt' or die $!;

#I am separating loop to reset values#
while (<MYFILE>) { 

    #finds all instances of USER
    $user++ if /USER/ig;
    #print "user" (use as check)

    #finds all instances of PASS
    $pass++ if /PASS/ig;
    #print "pass" (use as check)

}

#Output summary to new file: overwrite file
print OUT "SUMMARY REPORT:\n\n";

print OUT "# of total lines in the file = $.\n\n\n";

print OUT "Range of time the file encompasses:\n\n
    Starting Time = $start_time\n\n
    Ending Time = $end_time\n\n
    Total Time = 16.219218\n\n\n";

print OUT "Total # of distinct SOURCE ip addresses = \n\n\n";

print OUT "Total # of distinct DESTINATION ip addresses = \n\n\n";

print OUT "Listing of distinct SOURCE ip addresses = \n\n\n";

print OUT "Listing of distinct DESTINATION ip addresses = \n\n\n";

print OUT "Total # of distinct SOURCE TCP ports = \n\n\n";

print OUT "Total # of distinct  DESTINATION TCP ports = \n\n\n";

print OUT "Listing of distinct SOURCE TCP ports = \n\n\n";

print OUT "Listing of distinct DESTINATION TCP ports = \n\n\n";

print OUT "Total # of times phrases were used:\n\n
    USER (variations thereof) = $user\n\n
    PASS (variations thereof) = $pass\n\n\n";

print OUT "DETAIL SECTION:\n\n\n";

print OUT "SOURCE IP address activity by port over time:\n\n
    Mean packet size for above = \n\n
    Median packet size for above = \n\n\n";

print OUT "Detail IP address activity by port over time:\n\n
    Mean packet size for above = \n\n
    Median packet size for above = \n\n\n";

print OUT "Any and all interesting text w/in the DATA section of the file:\n\n";
close OUT;              #
close OUTFILE;          #close remaining files
close MYFILE;           #
```

Comment: Could you show us the contents of `source_file.txt`?

Comment: I don't think it's incrementing at all. Move the last print statement to inside the `while...if..` just under `pass++` to print out the values for each iteration of the loop.

Comment: `$linenum` also known as the built-in `$.`

Comment: yea i tried that, you don't want to even see the weird output I get if I do that.

Comment: Actually, we do want to see that... that's the point.

Comment: if i use $., my number of lines double to 4012 instead of 2006 for some reason..

Comment: I assume you're not being silly and trying to increment `$.`?

Comment: I just pasted your sample text 6 times and ran the code, getting USER=6, PASS=0. Not sure there's anything wrong with your script at all?

Comment: I don't know how you could run my code when you do not have the full input file im running..and it is suppossed to yield 3 for user and 2 for pass..

Comment: Time to learn to use the perl debugger.

Comment: @user2288 I literally took the code you posted here, created a text file with that ^ sample line in it 6 times, and executed the PERL script. The outputted file `Summary_Report.txt` showed USER=6 and PASS=0. Try it yourself with just that code and you'll see.

Comment: @user2288 There is nothing obvious in the code that would make it do what you say it does. Create a small input file that replicates the behaviour you describe and post it here. (I also got the same result as r3mus)

Comment: @r3mus sorry i misunderstood what you were getting at, and your right it worked when I tried what you said, but then I go back to my code and it fails again.

Comment: Right -- so you've ruled out the code ^ so you probably need to look elsewhere ;)

Comment: in case you guys are wondering, I closed the file after the first while loop, reopened it using the same code, and then used a new while loop and only inserted the USER and PASS counters and it worked.

Comment: What you are saying does not make sense, given your code and input. If I were to guess, I would say that you've posted approximate code, and not the code you are using, and that in your code you have declared inside the loop `my $user; my $pass;` (which would shadow your other variables with the same name).

Comment: I posted them outside the loop because I know they need to be used in my output statement. I am only a beginner, please do not assume. -_-

Comment: One note, `if /.../g` makes no sense. Should be `if /.../`. It won't always cause problems, but it can.

Comment: @user2288 You would be surprised at how many times I've seen people post code they do not actually have. Generally speaking, I only make assumptions when information is lacking, which it was in this case. You should always create an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) when posting code, if it is possible. It makes it possible for people to see your problem and apply their own tests and solutions on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a few observations. Maybe this will help:

Let's take at your loop:

```
while (<MYFILE>) {                                 # 1
    chomp;                                         # 2
    if (/^\d+:\d+/) {                              # 3
        my @header = split (/\s+/, $_);            # 4
        print OUTFILE "$linenum: @header\n\n";     # 5
        if (/^22:28/ && !defined($start_time)) {   # 6
            $start_time = $header[0];              # 7
        }
        if (/22:28/) {                             # 8
            $end_time = $header[0];                # 9
        }
        $user++ if /USER/ig;                       # 10
        $pass++ if /PASS/ig;                       # 11
    }
}
```

You realize that `$user++` and `$pass++` are inside the if statement (Line #3). It looks like it should work because all of your lines match the regular expression. Line #5 prints out to `Header.txt`. Are you getting any output in `Header.txt`? If not, there is something wrong with your `if` statement on Line #3.

If you are getting output in `Header.txt`, we can use `grep` and `wc` to count the number of times we get `USER` and `PASS`:

```
$ grep /USER/i Header.txt | wc -l   # The total you should get for $user
$ grep /PASS/i Header.txt | wc -l   # The total you should get for $pass
```

If these are both zero, we know that you are not finding lines that will increment `$user` and `$pass`.

Another thing I notices is that you're using the default variable `$_` all over the place. This may be causing problems because the value of `$_` could be getting replaced on you. I don't see anything off hand, but it is possible that by the time you get to lines #10 and #11, `$_` is not set to the line you read in.

You should almost always use a lexically scoped local variable -- especially with loops that contain more than just a few lines:

```
while ( my $line = <MYFILE> ) {
    chomp $line;
    if ( $line =~ /^\d=:\d+/ ) {
    ....
    if ( $line =~ /USER/i ) {
       $user += 1;
    }
    if ( $line =~ /PASS/i ) {
       $pass += 1;
    }
}
```

This in itself may solve your problem -- especially if you've shortened your loop to post what you thought was relevant information. Others commenters have tried your single line of input and report your code works for them. It could be that you might be doing something to change the value of `$_` and didn't put it in your coding sample.

Notice that I use a pre-fixed `if` instead of a post-fixed `if`. It makes the code a bit clearer because someone scanning your code may miss the post fixed `if. Also, it makes it clearer that a single line may be counted twice if they both contain` USER`and`PASS`. Is this something that may happen?

Lines #6 though #9 seem a bit weird to me. What if the start time isn't 10:28pm? Why do both `$start_time` and `$end_time` seem to be looking at the same thing? Is there something going on with the end time because I noticed that Line #8 doesn't have that start-of-line anchor that Line #6 has.

Why not simply make the first line read in, the `$start_time`, and the last line read in the `$end_time`?

Also, you do a `split`, but you don't seem to do anything with the data (except for the first part). It maybe more efficient doing a `substr` to pull off the data you want:

```
my $time_stamp = substr( $line, 0, 15 );
```

This way, it's obvious you simply want the first part of the line for a time stamp, and you're not concerned with the rest of the line. Users who are looking at your code aren't wondering what you plan to do with that data. Plus, you get to use a nice meaningful name. Ah!, this is a `$time_stamp` and not some meaningless `$header[0]`. Also, with the `substr`, you could trim down the value from `22:28:31.819551` to just `22:28:31`:

```
my $time_stamp = substr( $line, 0, 8 );
```

Again, I don't see anything wrong. I've tried generating a bunch of data based upon your lines and ran them through your code, but what you have seems to work. Is that loop longer than what you posted?

---

## ADDENDUM

There are several things. You're using `my` to *define* variables at the very beginning of your program as if you're writing in COBOL or Pascal. The advantage of `my` is to allow variable scoping. A variable defined with `my` is lexically scoped. That is, it exists only in the block it's created. This can help you catch errors.

Don't define all of your variables at the beginning of your program. Define them to take advantage of the scoping mechanism. For example, let's take `@header`. This is only used in your loop. Define it there:

```
while (my $line = <MYFILE>) { # Don't use `$_`. Use a real variable!
chomp $line; #break new line
 my @header = split /\s+/, $line;  # Define @header here!

if ( $line =~ /^\d+:\d+/ ) {
    print OUTFILE "$.: $line\n\n"; # {rint $line instead of gluing @header back together
```

Each time you go through the loop, `@header` will become undefined once again. Pure and clean for the next line you're parsing. This way, you don't have to worry about previous values in `@header` getting in your way.

Also, your loop is now long enough that `$_` will probably get you into trouble. Use a real life variable that's lexically scoped (like I did with `$line`. It's obvious what `$line` contains. It isn't always obvious what `$_` may be -- even to you.

Also, take a look at this line:

```
@dest_ip = split ('\.', $header[4]);
$dest_ip[$i] = $dest_ip[0] . '.' . $dest_ip[1] . '.' . $dest_ip[2] . '.' . $dest_ip[3];
```

If I'm reading it correctly, you have a variable `$i` that you're incrementing, what is going on with each line you're parsing. Yet, you're overwriting `@dest_ip` each and every time.

Why are you even doing this? What are you trying to do? You're splitting the IP into four groups, putting them back together in `$dest_ip[$line_number]`, then destroying `@dest_ip` with your split.

You should look into using a Perl module since you're really going through parsing your Apache httpd log (I believe it's an Apache httpd log). Take a look at [Apache::LogRegex](https://metacpan.org/pod/Apache::LogRegex) and see if it can relieve you of much of the parsing you're doing to get the data you want.

Comment: I posted as an answer my full code, what i posted turns no errors so far.

Comment: @user2288 See my addendum.

Comment: seeing my full code, do you think I should make your changes still? It all works so I am nervous to mess it up.

Comment: @ David W. In case you were still curious about my though process, I went and asked my professor the purpose of splitting the @dest_ip and then rebuilding it because I was also confused by it and he gave me this response...

Comment: "The reason we would split that value up is because we need an ip address and a port.  Unfortunately, they are both packed into a single field separated by periods.  Because of this, we breakup the entire field by periods by splitting it into a new array.  We can then use that array to pull out the first four elements, which are the IP address and then the last element is the port.  That leaves us with source ip and source port."

Comment: so, basically my assignment is to take this input file he gave up which is made up of many IP addresses and to find the ip and port. the issue is that these ip's given in the input file are quintuplets, and we know IP's are quadruples, so the first four sections ex 144.25.199.266 is the IP address and the .1822 is the port. Not sure what you know about ports but it can be a mail port, html port, etc. The project is designed to make us examine the port numbers and find out what this hacker was trying to do. does that clarify?

Comment: Okay, the array has five bits, and you just want the first four. However, you're using the same array with the index`$i` counting up for each record, yet you're destroying that same array each time. I would probably use a regex to simply remove the port `$ip_addr =~ s/\.\d+$//' instead of using split and then rebuild it.